# setting up selenium webdriver on aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, lambda, webdriver, layer

this is my code and i have added  [image]

this is my code and i have added 2 layer of selenium and webdriver dont know what the issue is .

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Message: Unable to locate or obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location\n",
  "errorType": "NoSuchDriverException",
  "requestId": "de4bb9e6-8350-4e36-804b-073ab4791375",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 13, in lambda_handler\n    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py\", line 45, in __init__\n    super().__init__(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py\", line 51, in __init__\n    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py\", line 44, in get_path\n    raise NoSuchDriverException(f\"Unable to locate or obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']}\")\n"
  ]
}
dont know where to fix this i tried eerything is anyone where is available to connect on anydesk
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, attach code instead.